# Custom Border control in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

You can make custom panels in UWP XAML by deriving from the `Panel` class and overriding `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`. How would I go about doing the same thing for a panel with just one child, similar to the `Border` control? Unfortunately, I cannot derive from `Border` because it's sealed.

I tried this but it doesn't work (of course, this is a simplified sample for what I'm trying to achieve):

```
public sealed class ProportionedPresenter : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Child",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(ProportionedPresenter),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object Child
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(ProportionedPresenter.ChildProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ProportionedPresenter.ChildProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var minDimension = Math.Min(availableSize.Width, availableSize.Height);
        var desiredSize = new Size(minDimension, minDimension);
        if (this.Child is UIElement childElement)
        {
            childElement.Measure(desiredSize);
            var maxDimension = Math.Max(childElement.DesiredSize.Width, childElement.DesiredSize.Height);
            desiredSize = new Size(maxDimension, maxDimension);
        }
        return desiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if (this.Child is UIElement childElement)
        {
            childElement.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), childElement.DesiredSize));
        }
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you just want to change the styling of the control or do you want to change the behavior of the control itself?

Comment: Did you want to make a container control and only one UIElement can be inside it? If there're multi UIElements in it, the visual studio should throw intellisense error 
like the border?

Comment: @Daniel I'm trying to change the behavior of the control - customize how the child gets sized

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Yes, I want my control to only have one child.

Comment: @KMehta You could try to make your class derive from `Panel` class. In its `MeasureOverride`, you could detect the count of `Children`. If the count>1, you could throw exception or do other operation.